# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Task<(IEnumerable<Item>, int)>' and 'Task<IEnumerable<Item>>'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, moq

I had the following function to be mocked.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItems(int total);
}
```

And my mocking code was

```
private readonly IEnumerable<Item> stubList = new List<Item> { new Item { } };

mockRepository = Mock.Of<IRepository>(r => r.GetItems(50) == Task.FromResult(stubList));
```

It worked on both my desktop (Visual studio 2017) and msbuild (`MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.8.169.51996' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin'`) on Jenkin server.

Now the method has been changed to

```
public interface IRepository
{
    Task<(IEnumerable<Item>, int)> GetItems(int total);
}
```

And the mocking code was changed to

```
private readonly IEnumerable<Item> stubList = new List<Item> { new Item { } };

var m = (stubList, 1);
mockRepository = Mock.Of<IRepository>(r => r.GetItems(50) == Task.FromResult(m));
```

It still works on my desktop (visual studio 2017). But msbuild failed with the following error message?

`error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 
   'Task<(IEnumerable<Item>, int)>' and 'Task<IEnumerable<Item>>'`

build.log:

> CoreResGen:
>     "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\Resgen.exe" /useSourcePath /r:"D:\Jenkins\workspace...\packages\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.2.8.1\lib\net35\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll" /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.JScript.dll /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Design.dll /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.ServiceModel.dll" /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.Services.dll /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\WindowsBase.dll" /compile Components\CheckedComboBox\PopupComboBox.resx,obj\Release\PresentationControls.PopupComboBox.resources Components\DGV\DgvDesignerColumnList.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.DgvDesignerColumnList.resources Components\DGV\frmGridColumnsExt.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmGridColumnsExt.resources Components\DGV\dgv.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.DGV.resources Components\DGV\frmChangeGridState.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmChangeGridState.resources Components\DGV\frmGridColumns.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmGridColumns.resources Components\UserControl_Folder.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.UserControl_Folder.resources frmDropDownBox.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmDropDownBox.resources frmUsersChangeHistory.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmUsersChangeHistory.resources frmUserPermissions.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmUserPermissions.resources frmUserRegProdGroups.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmUserRegProdGroups.resources frmErrorBox.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmErrorBox.resources frmGridBox.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmGridBox.resources frmInputBox.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmInputBox.resources frmLongTask.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmLongTask.resources frmNoteBox.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmNoteBox.resources Components\MonthPicker.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.MonthPicker.resources frmUserGroups.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmUserGroups.resources frmUsers.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmUsers.resources Properties\Resources.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.Properties.Resources.resources Reports\frmEditReports.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmEditReports.resources Reports\frmJobsMaintenance.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmJobsMaintenance.resources Reports\frmRunReports.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmRunReports.resources Reports\frmSelectReport.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmSelectReport.resources Reports\frmShowReportLog.resx,obj\Release\Infrastructure.frmShowReportLog.resources

Comment: You cannot compare `Task<(IEnumerable<Item>, int)>` and `Task<IEnumerable<Item>>`. The former is a task of enumerable of tuple of Item and int, the latter is a task of enumerable of Item. You see?

Comment: This is not the issue. The code doesn't compare with different type. The error message is a little bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the more verbose approach instead of the [LINQ to Mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks)

```
private readonly IEnumerable<Item> stubList = new List<Item> { new Item { } };

//...

var expected = (stubList, 1);

var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
mock
    .Setup(_ => _.GetItems(50))
    .ReturnsAsync(expected); 

IRepository mockRepository = mock.Object;

//...
```

The framework may be having issues trying to evaluate the expression with the new syntax

Comment: msbuild working now. Thanks. Why Linq to Mock failed on msbuild though?

Comment: @ca9163d9 The framework probably could not evaluate the expression with the new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stubList = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item()
        };

        var m = (stubList, 1);

        var mockRepository = Mock.Of<IRepository>(r => r.GetItems(50) == Task.FromResult(m));
    }
}

interface IRepository
{
    Task<(IEnumerable<Item>, int)> GetItems(int total);
}

class Item
{
}
```

I'm getting different compiler error:

> CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Task<(IEnumerable, int)>' and 'Task<(List stubList, int)>'

This happens because you compare `Task<(List<Item>, int)>` and `Task<(IEnumerable<Item>, int)>`. `Task<T>` is not [co-variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) (opposite to `List<T>` for instance) so the error is expected.

But why your question contains different compiler error?

---

If I change the code to this:

```
var m = ((IEnumerable<Item>)stubList, 1);
```

or this:

```
(IEnumerable<Item>, int) m = (stubList, 1);
```

then it complies fine.

Comment: The `stubList` in my code is defined as a field with the type of `IEnumerable<Item>`.

Comment: @ca9163d9: Oh, right, I see. Then it's not an issue, I cannot reproduce it.